# web shop solution for tour booking office

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart

Hope this is the right place to ask.

A customer asked me to develop a web shop for his tour booking office. Now I'd rather use an existing system instead of building one. There are special requirements for tour booking shops, though:

1. "date of purchase" is relevant, you always book a tour for a certain date
2. different prices for different dates, a tour might cost more or less next year
3. immediate checkout, customers buy only one item and don't want to use a shopping cart

Question: Is there an existing solution that I could use? Is it possible to tweak a system like zencart to fit the requirements?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this question is still open: In the end I went with a custom development using the Yii framework. Gives me a very flexible solution with an affordable effort.

Answer (score 0):

Visit www.odissia.net > Booking Software > Tour booking software

Comment: Thank you for the link. The system doesn't look too solid to me though. I'll probably go with a custom module for ubercart.